# How to import collection and nested collection data in cloud firestore using node js?

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to import   collection and nested collection data in cloud firestore using node js?

I used this code for import from json file to cloud firesore database but its only imported on collection data only

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("./servicekey.json");
const data = require("./data.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "database-url";
});
data && Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const nestedContent = data[key];

    if (typeof nestedContent === "object") {
        Object.keys(nestedContent).forEach(docTitle => {
            admin.firestore()
                .collection(key)
                .doc(docTitle)
                .set(nestedContent[docTitle])
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log("Document successfully written!",res);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                });
        });
    }
});
```

My json file format this file can have collecion and subcollectiondata or nested collection data

```
{
     "messages2": {
     "1585135109814test": {
         "Ref_Chat_Type": 1,
         "Last_Content_Time": "1585135492165",
         "Member_Ids": ["xxx", "yyy"],
         "AdminUsers": ["yyy"],
         "Group_Desc": "Ttt",
         "Members": [{
             "User_Profile_Pic": null,
             "User_Id": "xxx",
             "User_Name": "vvv"
         }, {
             "User_Name": "sss",
             "User_Profile_Pic": "",
             "User_Id": "yyy"
         }, {
             "User_Name": "rrr",
             "User_Profile_Pic": "",
             "User_Id": "zzz"
         }],
         "Last_Content": "vhh",
         "Last_Content_From_Id": "yyy",
         "Group_Name": "Test",
         "Group_Id": "1585135109814test",
         "Last_Content_From_Username": "vvv",
         "Group_Pic": "",
         "subCollection": {
             "messages2/1585135109814test/1585135109814test": {
                 "0NBKTa2Py9HvRK0yNxLa": {
                     "Ref_Content_type": 1,
                     "Content_Timestamp": 1588673106,
                     "From_Id": "xxx",
                     "Content_Id": "0NBKTa2Py9HvRK0yNxLa",
                     "Group_Id": "1585135109814test",
                     "From_User_Profile_Pic": "",
                     "Content": "55",
                     "Content_Read_By": null,
                     "From_Username": "vvv"
                 }

         }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

i used the batch concept this code i comes an error on

C:\xampp\htdocs\task>node importmain.js

ERROR:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:101
>               throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.NO_APP, errorMessage);
>               ^
>
> FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure
>   you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.
>       at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
>       at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
>       at new FirebaseAppError (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\utils\error.js:122:28)
>       at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.app (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\firebase-namespace.js:101:19)
>       at FirebaseNamespace.app (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\firebase-namespace.js:402:30)
>       at FirebaseNamespace.ensureApp (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\firebase-namespace.js:418:24)
>       at FirebaseNamespace.fn (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules[4mfirebase-admin[24m\lib\firebase-namespace.js:327:30)
>       at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\task\importmain.js:4:16) [90m    at Module._compile
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)[39m [90m    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)[39m {   errorInfo: {
>       code: [32m'app/no-app'[39m,
>       message: [32m'The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase
>   services.'[39m   },   codePrefix: [32m'app'[39m }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the initialization of `firebase-admin`.

As per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin),
the right syntax is the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

You should call `admin.initializeApp()` without any parameters.

Please try that and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, with one call to a Firestore "document write method" (e.g. [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set), [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) or [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add)), write to a document and to documents of its subcollection(s).

**You need to combine several calls.**

The recommended way is to use a batched write, as follow:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
let batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of Parent
var pRef = db.collection(key).doc(docTitle);
batch.set(pRef, {...});

// Set the value of Child
var cRef = db.collection(key).doc(docTitle).collection("....").doc("...");
batch.set(cRef, {...});

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

---

So, concretely, you need to parse your json in such a way that you generate the documents/collections paths and the corresponding JavaScript Objects to be passed to the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#set) method of the Batched Write.

Comment: I used the batch concept this code i comes an error 

C:\xampp\htdocs\task\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js:101 throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.NO_APP, errorMessage); ^

FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services. at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor]

Comment: without batch i execute the program  data comes on unstructure on firestore database